# How do I replace part of result coming from Database with predefined text

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am working on MVC ASP.net project. In my project I need to generate java script. Here I am generating script by fetching result from Database.

Now problem I am facing is, in database, results is stored as cartText1550. But I need to display this result as rowText1550.

This is my code :

```
QrString += "document.getElementById(\"" + results.QrField.ToString() + "\").style.display = \"none\";" + "<br />";
```

Here I have result from DB, in **results.QrField**, which is cartText1550.

So can someone tell me how can i replace cartText with rowText here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems just a matter of calling the Replace method of the string class

```
results.QrField.ToString().Replace("cart", "row")
```